# Dataset listing datasets for natural language processing

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a dataset listing datasets for natural language processing with as many following fields as possible:

- name
- annotations (e.g., part of speech, dependency parses, or named entities)
- [annotation scheme](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/17181/2680)
- size

Answer (score 3):

Such a list requires someone to maintain it. This one lists corpora and adds some info, covering some if not all of your criteria (in natural language): [Corpora, Collections, Data Archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405015039/http://www.uow.edu.au/%7Edlee/corpora.htm)